# Is there any valid way to show dummy scroll bar in firefox?

Tags: css

Is there any valid way to show dummy scroll bar in firefox?

Comment: Define "dummy"...do you mean it isn't actually usable, or it should appear, whether there is more content to scroll or not?

Comment: I just have to ask...why? Most designers try to eliminate them or at least make them look pretty :)

Comment: @Tommy - Because of page shift in firefox . because In Internet Explorer (IE) (and older versions of Opera), space is reserved for the vertical scrollbar even when it is not needed

Comment: @MGS - Thanks, I learned something new tonight!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want scrollbars to test the look of having a bar, try setting the overflow property:

```
body { overflow:scroll; }
```

This will force Firefox to display a scrollbar for your window. For a vertical bar only, use overflow-y instead:

```
body { overflow-y:scroll; }
```

This is the best way to force scroll bars.

Comment: i want to keep dummy scrollbar forever in firefox. even if content is shorter than available height

Comment: The above style will display a scrollbar all the time, even if the content is shorter than the available height. If you had wanted only to set optional scrollbars (the default behavior) you would set overflow to "auto" instead. "scroll" forces a scrollbar to display.

Comment: @alex - but this is not valid css

Comment: @metal - Sure it is, and supported for a long time, just now becoming part of the spec: http://www.css3.com/css-overflow-y/

Comment: @Nick Craver - +1 Oh yes you are right it's valid with css3 option in Validator

Comment: @Joseph Mastey - yes i will go for `html { overflow-y:scroll; }` Thanks